# SQL How can I copy a csv file into a table with this delimiter problem?

Tags: sql, csv, t-sql, copy, delimiter

I'm trying to copy a csv file into a table. The delimiter is ',' but the csv file has a field named 'Description' where it also uses ',' but not as a delimiter. As part of a text. 
How could I copy the csv file into the Import table?

[image: This image shows the csv file forma]

[image: This image shows how I'm trying to copy the data]

Answer (score 0):

If the comma is always within the double quotes then it shouldn't be a problem.

If not, you have a corrupt CSV file. The simplest way is probably to parse your file prior to importing to fix the corruption.

The details of how exactly to parse will depend on the dataset. Which fields are optional? which fields are compulsory? How many commas can occur at most? That kind of information is crucial for writing a parsing script.